# Number Guessing in 7 Steps Python

Tags: python, math

I want to write a python game that knows the number(1-100) taken from a user in 7 steps at most. 
2^7>100.
The code below is working but it takes more than 7 steps. I think the problem is guess=guess+-guess//(2^n) part. But I dont know what to replace with.

```
number=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
guess=50
n=1
if number>100:
    number=int(input("Enter a number less than 100: "))
if number<1:
    number=int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))
while True:
    print("Your number is" +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "?")
    ans=str(input("(g)reater,(l)ess or (b)ravo: "))
    for n in range(1,10,1):
        if ans=="g":
            guess=guess+guess//(2^n)
        elif ans=="l":
            guess=guess-guess//(2^n)
        elif ans=="b":
            print("Your number is " +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "Well done for me")
        break
```

Comment: First thing is that '^' is not the exponent opeator in python, Try '**' instead.

Comment: Also, try keeping track of the highest and lowest number that you know the answer can be in, and then narrow the guess within that range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of your lowest and highest possible numbers and then make guess that lies halfway between them. Update the lowest and highest numbers based on reply.

```
number=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
guess = 50
n = 1
if number>100:
    number=int(input("Enter a number less than 100: "))
if number<1:
    number=int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

lo = 1
hi = 100

while True:
    print("Your number is" +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "?")
    ans = str(input("(g)reater,(l)ess or (b)ravo: "))
    if ans == "g":
        lo = guess
        guess=lo + (hi-lo+1)//2
    elif ans == "l":
        hi = guess
        guess=lo + (hi-lo)//2
    elif ans == "b":
        print("Your number is " +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "Well done for me")
        break 
    n += 1
```